# error when executing Jenkins build

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, webdriver

I have encountered a strange issue. i have recently transferred my Jenkins builds from a server to my local system with the help of job import plugin. tests were building fine on the server with out any issues. after transfer i have noticed that the builds started failing on the server, with following issues.

```
[WARNING] The POM for com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:jar:4.0.2206.100 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.000 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-30T07:06:16+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/172M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project ------: Could not resolve dependencies for project ------:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:jar:4.0.2206.100 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

funny thing is the build is running fine on my local system with out any issues. but they are failing on the server. its the same branch i am building on both the machines.  cant seem to get to the bottom of this. 
any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft does not provide sqljdbc4.jar to maven central repository.

You should download it from [Microsoft website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774)

And install manually on your jenkins server using mvn:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
    -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

Howeever, Microsoft open sourced their mysql-jdbc so you can try [this one](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jdbcteam/2016/11/17/open-source-jdbc-maven/) insteed of your.

Comment: It's available through the clojars-repository.  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/sqljdbc4/4.0

Comment: I saw that, but try to add it to your pom and auto import. It wouldn't work.

Comment: If you add `<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>clojars.org</id>
            <url>http://clojars.org/repo/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>` it works like a charm.

Comment: hi there,thanks for the reply. i have this dependency in the pom and i have loaded the jdbc driver files in the project folder, which mean that where ever the project is downloaded the files are also downloaded. what i am perplexed about is the fact that the build is running fine on the local jenkins instance but not on the server. its the same branch that is build in both the cases. if the pom could not find the driver then how come its building it fine in the local machine i wonder?

Comment: Because you downloaded it earlier manually, or from maven central. Now it is not available anymore so you need to download it and install on your jenkins server.

Comment: Hi Sovas,i have put this dependency in my pom file                                             https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jdbcteam/2016/11/17/open-source-jdbc-maven/     tests are building however i dont see the browser opening

Comment: Is the project building now?

Comment: yes project is building but browser is not opening .i can see that tests are passing as i have system out response being generated after every test

Comment: So this fix your issue "error when executing Jenkins build". If you want help with another one, you should post another thread. Cheers.

Comment: thanks a lot Sovas! i shall post a different question for that.